# How do I set the border color in a Spark TextArea?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

How do I set the border color in a Spark TextArea? There is no attribute style for borderColor in Spark TextArea.

```
<s:TextArea id="textarea" borderColor="0"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the style as shown below:

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <fx:Style>
        @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
        @namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";

        s|TextArea#txtArea1 {
            borderColor: red;
        }

    </fx:Style>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:TextArea id="txtArea1" width="500" height="500" skinClass="MyCustomTextAreaSkin">

    </s:TextArea>
</s:Application>
```

If you have other requirements as well then better go with a custom skin. This example outputs what you want.

Comment: I've accepted your answer but it works inline as well. The problem with inline is that it doesn't show up in auto complete.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the compiler does not know about this style attribute. It does not autocomplete like other styles but it does not throw an error either. It appears to work at runtime.